# Difference between a non-associated array and an associated array where the keys are string intergers

Tags: php, arrays

Are the following three arrays identical, or can they be told apart?  If so, how?

```
$array1=array('abc','def','ghi');
$array2=array('0'=>'abc','1'=>'def','2'=>'ghi');
$array3=array(0=>'abc',1=>'def',2=>'ghi');
```

Comment: Ehhhh? Compare var_dump($array1), var_dump($array2) and var_dump($array3) and get along with its results? ;) Cheers

Comment: @lin  I expected them to be different, but my initial testing indicated that they were identical.  Didn't use var_dump, but have since done so and they also appear to be identical.

Comment: "to be identical" -> "it is identical". Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple test would have prevented this confusion for you.

```
<?php

$array1=array('abc','def','ghi');
$array2=array('0'=>'abc','1'=>'def','2'=>'ghi');
$array3=array(0=>'abc',1=>'def',2=>'ghi');

print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);
print_r($array3);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => def
    [2] => ghi
)
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => def
    [2] => ghi
)
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => def
    [2] => ghi
)
```

Do you see any difference? None whatsoever.

> Are the following three arrays identical, or can they be told apart?

Yes they are identical and no they cannot be told apart.

Note this example from [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

```
<?php
$array = array(
    1    => "a",
    "1"  => "b",
    1.5  => "c",
    true => "d",
);
var_dump($array);
?>
```

Read this

> As all the keys in the above example are cast to 1, the value will be overwritten on every new element and the last assigned value "d" is the only one left over.

That means your `0` and `"0"` mean the same thing, the end :)

Comment: Yes, I see there is no difference. Just didn't believe it at first :)  God bless the scientific method!

Comment: Ah, thanks for the extra part about type casting the values. That explains it!

Comment: Cheers, arrays are very interesting in PHP. They are more like an ordered map rather than usual arrays in other languages

Answer (score 1):

They appear the same to me, both in data and functionality:

```
<?php

$array1=array('abc','def','ghi');
$array2=array('0'=>'abc','1'=>'def','2'=>'ghi');
$array3=array(0=>'abc',1=>'def',2=>'ghi');

var_dump($array1); // array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "abc" [1]=> string(3) "def" [2]=> string(3) "ghi" } 

var_dump($array2); // array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "abc" [1]=> string(3) "def" [2]=> string(3) "ghi" } 

var_dump($array3); // array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "abc" [1]=> string(3) "def" [2]=> string(3) "ghi" }

echo $array1[0]; // abc
echo $array1['0']; // abc
echo $array2[0]; // abc
echo $array2['0']; // abc
echo $array3[0]; // abc
echo $array3['0']; // abc

array_push($array2, 'jik');

var_dump($array2); // array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "abc" [1]=> string(3) "def" [2]=> string(3) "ghi" [3]=> string(3) "jik" }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not identical because you can call the first one by `$array1[0]` and will output "abc". The second one the key has to be not in quotes or else it will think it is a string. `$array2["0"]` will output "abc" and `$array[0]` will too. The third one is identical with the first one though, since the key is provided without quotes. `$array[3]` will output "abc".

Comment: Are you sure?  I expected the same as you, but my testing indicates that it is not the case.

Comment: Apparently I was wrong, here is a look at the string types and integers. @user1032531 check out http://us3.php.net//manual/en/types.comparisons.php and http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Comment: Updated answer. I thought that wouldn't happen, weird... @lin

Comment: What's wrong about the new answer? @lin could you explain this to me?

Comment: Look at @shennan answer, he debugged it for us :)